# Rails first_or_create ActiveRecord method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rails-activerecord

What does the `first_or_create` / `first_or_create!` method do in Rails?

According to the [documentation](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Relation/first_or_create), the method "*has no description*"...

Answer (score 67, accepted):

From the [Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.13/active_record_querying.html#first_or_create)

**first_or_create**

The `first_or_create` method checks whether `first` returns nil or not. If it does return nil, then `create` is called. This is very powerful when coupled with the `where` method. Let’s see an example.

Suppose you want to find a client named ‘Andy’, and if there’s none, create one and additionally set his locked attribute to false. You can do so by running:

```
Client.where(:first_name => 'Andy').first_or_create(:locked => false)
# => #<Client id: 1, first_name: "Andy", orders_count: 0, locked: false, created_at: "2011-08-30 06:09:27", updated_at: "2011-08-30 06:09:27">
```

The SQL generated by this method looks like this:

```
SELECT * FROM clients WHERE (clients.first_name = 'Andy') LIMIT 1
BEGIN
INSERT INTO clients (created_at, first_name, locked, orders_count, updated_at) VALUES ('2011-08-30 05:22:57', 'Andy', 0, NULL, '2011-08-30 05:22:57')
COMMIT
```

`first_or_create` returns either the record that already exists or the new record. In our case, we didn’t already have a client named Andy so the record is created and returned.

**first_or_create!**

You can also use `first_or_create!` to raise an exception if the new record is invalid. Validations are not covered on this guide, but let’s assume for a moment that you temporarily add

```
validates :orders_count, :presence => true
```

to your Client model. If you try to create a new Client without passing an orders_count, the record will be invalid and an exception will be raised:

```
Client.where(:first_name => 'Andy').first_or_create!(:locked => false)
# => ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: Orders count can't be blank
```

Comment: Hey @Pavan, after using first_or_create is there a way to know if the record already existed or was created? Right now I am using "exists?" but I think this is redundant.

Answer (score 3):

I believe `first_or_create` should generally be avoided these days. (Although it's still in [Rails 6.1.1](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/main/activerecord/lib/active_record/relation.rb#L118-L128).) In 4.0 they added [`find_or_create_by`](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/eb72e62c3042c0df989d951b1d12291395ebdb8e) and [friends](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/4-0-stable/activerecord/CHANGELOG.md), which are apparently meant to replace the `first_or_create` methods. `first_or_create` was once mentioned in the [guides](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.2/active_record_querying.html#find-or-build-a-new-object), now it's [not](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/v4.0/active_record_querying.html#find-or-build-a-new-object). And it is no longer documented [in the code](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/0096f53b25e68c3fc79429253f816fff4a4ee596#diff-18a561656864ea240daf46bdb1f50faace49f9ef74b90bcf667d9bbb17fce084) (since Rails 4.0). It was introduced in [Rails 3.2.19](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/84dad446c6a23a15f67b9d558e8039891a008bff).

The reasons are:

- It might seem that `first_or_create(attrs)` does `first(attrs) || create(attrs)`, where in fact it does `first || create(attrs)`. The proper usage is:

  ```
  Model.where(search_attrs).first_or_create(create_attrs)
  ```

  That is, it might confuse people. `first(attrs) || create(attrs)` is what `find_or_create_by` does.
- Also, using `first_or_create` introduces a scope, that might affect the `create` callbacks in an unexpected way.

More on it in the [changelog](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/4-0-stable/activerecord/CHANGELOG.md) (search for `first_or_create`).

Answer (score 1):

Gets the first record that matches what you have specified or creates one if there are no matches

Comment: It just gets the first record and doesn't do: "matches what you have specified"

Answer (score 1):

If you check the source, you will see that they are almost identical. The only difference is that the first one calls the "create" method and the other one "create!". This means that the second one will raise an exception, if the creation is not successful.