# first_or_create vs find_or_create_by

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

`first_or_create` seems much less documented, so I wondered if it was just because the two methods are synonymous.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Basically:

```
Foo.where(attributes).first_or_create
```

Is the same as:

```
Foo.find_or_create_by(attributes)
```

---

`#first_or_create` is sometimes misunderstood as people expect it to search by the attributes given, but that is not the case. Aka

```
Foo.first_or_create(attributes)
```

Will not search for a `foo` that satisfies the `attributes`. It will take the first `foo` if any are present. It's useful if the conditions for finding are a subset of those used for creation. Aka

```
Foo.where(something: value).first_or_create(attributes)
```

Will find the first `foo` where `something: value`. If none is present, it will use `attributes` to create it.

Comment: These two are not the same in terms of the SQL they execute, however. `first_or_create` will use an `ORDER BY id LIMIT 1` whereas `find_or_create_by` will simply use a `LIMIT 1`.

This doesn't matter in most scenarios, but as your dataset grows you may find this small difference can slow things down by orders of magnitude (even with indexes in place).

Comment: This is indeed the case and means that `find_or_*_by` ought to be the preferred syntax over `where(..).first_or_*`

Comment: The commit [nodoc the first_or_create methods and document alternatives](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/0096f53b25e68c3fc79429253f816fff4a4ee596)  explains why it is less documented.

Comment: Yep, there's more to it then just possible confusion. More on it in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65998519/52499). @Saul `first_or_create` appeared in [Rails 3.2.19](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/84dad446c6a23a15f67b9d558e8039891a008bff) and was sort of deprecated in [Rails 4.0](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/0096f53b25e68c3fc79429253f816fff4a4ee596#diff-18a561656864ea240daf46bdb1f50faace49f9ef74b90bcf667d9bbb17fce084). During that time its code didn't change much. It all comes down to `first`, which orders by `id` unless some other ordering is specified explicitly.

Comment: I might be missing something, but I doubt `first_or_create` ever suppressed the `ORDER BY` clause.

Answer (score 1):

@ndnenkov's answer is right on but I wanted to expand on why I think one might use `find_or_create`:

Consider the case when Foo must have either `attribute_subset_1` or `attribute_subset_2` before it can be created. One could (pseudo)code this as:

```
if attribute_subset_1 then
  Foo.where(attribute_subset_1).first_or_create(attributes)
elsif attribute_subset_2 then
  Foo.where(attribute_subset_2).first_or_create(attributes)
else
  Raise error " insufficient attributes"
end
```

This is a case where I think `find_or_create_by` does not work...at least not easily. I would be curious to hear if anything sees this differently but for me I found this use of `first_or_create` perfect for my needs.