# Seeding a database for an app with a has-many belongs to relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When seeding a database for a has_many belongs_to relationship your seeds.rb file should look something like this:

```
t1 = Tag.create(title: "Beaches", image: "beach01.jpg")
Destination.create(
  name: "Ipanema",
  description: "The beach of Ipanema is known for its elegant development and its social life.",
  image: "beach02.jpg",
  tag_id: t1.id
)
Destination.create(
  name: "7 Mile Beach",
  description: "The western coastline contains the island's finest beaches.",
  image: "beach03.jpg",
  tag_id: t1.id
)
Destination.create(
  name: "El Castillo",
  description: "An elite destination famous for its white sand beaches",
  image: "beach04.jpg",
  tag_id: t1.id
)
```

My question is what if your database is already seeded with the items in the has_many model and you just want to use rake db:seed with the items in the belongs_to model. I tried running rake db:seed with only the destinations.create and the references to tag with tag_id meaning I ran rake db:seed with just

```
Destination.create(
  name: "Ipanema", 
  description: "The beach of Ipanema is known for its elegant development and its social life.", 
  image: "beach02.jpg", 
  tag_id: t1.id
)
Destination.create(
  name: "7 Mile Beach", 
  description: "The western coastline contains the island's finest beaches.", 
  image: "beach03.jpg", 
  tag_id: t1.id
)
Destination.create(
  name: "El Castillo", 
  description: "An elite destination famous for its white sand beaches", 
  image: "beach04.jpg", 
  tag_id: t1.id
)
```

in my seeds.rb but I get a

> NameError: Undefined local variable or method t1 for main:Object.

Is there a way to seed the database with just the destinations if the tags are already in the database.

Answer (score 0):

You can find existing Tag with the `t1 = Tag.where(title: "Beaches", image: "beach01.jpg").first_or_create` statement

Comment: Upon trying it this didn't actually work. What is the .first_or_create statement for.

Comment: See this [SO article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42178674/first-or-create-vs-find-or-create-by)

Comment: What Rails version do you use?

Comment: And if you add `!` at the end, like `t1 = Tag.where(title: "Beaches", image: "beach01.jpg").first_or_create!` then you can see actual validation error

Comment: I use rails 5.1.4. When you use where can you just use t1=Tag.where(title: "Beaches") or do I have to specify all the tag parameters. I just used               t1 = Tag.where(title: "Beaches").first. I do not want to create multiple entries in the database and Tag also has other attributes like created_at and updated_at.

Comment: Yes, you can specify only `title` attribute in where condition.
And you also can try [find_or_create_by](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html#method-i-find_or_create_by) method, maybe it will be more clear.

Comment: I am getting an error. ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 2 expected  0..1) when I run rake db:seed