# How to find if reversed user input exists in database

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am creating a messenger system and I am using find_or_create_by to find the room in the database before creating one and that is working fine, but I have two ids, sender_id and receiver_id and I am trying to figure out how to check if there is an room instance in the database with the ids reversed before creating a new room.

Like if in the database room 1 has Sender_id = 1 and Receiver_id = 2.  If I try to create an instance where sender_id =2 and receiver_id = 1, I want it to load room 1 and not create a new instance.

rooms controller:

```
  def create

    @room = Room.find_or_create_by permitted_parameters

    if @room.save!
      redirect_to room_path(@room)
    else
      redirect_to rooms_path
    end
  end

  private

  def permitted_parameters
    params.require(:room).permit(:name, :sender_id, :receiver_id)
  end
```

the form to create is simple

```
<%= bootstrap_form_for @room do |f| %>
  <%= f.collection_select :receiver_id, User.all, :id, :first_name %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :sender_id, :value => current_user.id %>
  <%= f.submit "Save", class: 'btn btn-success' %>
<% end %>
```

room.rb

```
class Room < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user, optional: true
  has_many :messages, dependent: :destroy,
         inverse_of: :room
  has_many :users, {:through=>:messages, :source=>"user"}

end
```

message.rb

```
class Message < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user, :class_name => 'User', :foreign_key => "user_id"
  belongs_to :room, inverse_of: :messages
end
```

user.rb

```
  has_many :messages, :class_name => "Message", :foreign_key => "user_id"
  has_many :rooms, :foreign_key => "sender_id"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should tell you if the room is booked from either direction:

```rb
Room.where('(sender_id = :sender_id AND receiver_id = :receiver_id) OR
  (sender_id = :receiver_id AND receiver_id = :sender_id)', 
  sender_id: permitted_parameters[:sender_id], 
  receiver_id: permitted_parameters[:receiver_id]).first
```

If that comes back `.present?` you should know a room is booked.

---

Updated to remove `room` in where clause based on OP's comment.

Comment: I don't have a room column, so 'room = :room' is giving me an error.  Do I need that?

Comment: I got rid of the room parameters and it seems to be working fine.  Thanks so much!

Comment: The `room` part certainly dependent on your table/model so you were correct to take it out. Nice work!

Answer (score 1):

This May be helpful to you!

```
Room.where(sender_id: params[:sender_id],receiver_id: params[:receiver_id]).or(Room.where(receiver_id: params[:sender_id],sender_id: params[:receiver_id])).first_or_create
```

Comment: @DammitJanet its helpful?

Comment: That is a cool use of `first_or_create`. If folks want to know more about it and how it compares to `find_or_create_by` there is a good post here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42178674/first-or-create-vs-find-or-create-by

Comment: @Dan Thanks i am new to rails.